# Servant combinator doesn't fall through to subsequent alternatives

Tags: rest, haskell, servant

I made a custom combinator: `MultipartUpload`, but when I use it, it ends up applying not only the route I use it on, but all subsequent routes:

For example, in the following API, `MultipartUpload` runs on both the 2nd AND 3rd route. So if I call the 3rd it will return the error `File upload required`. I only want it to apply to the 2nd. How?

```
type ModelAPI =
  "models" :>
    (    ProjectKey :> Get '[JSON] [Model]
    :<|> ProjectKey :> MultipartUpload :> Post '[JSON] Model
    :<|> ProjectKey :> Capture "modelId" ID :> Get '[JSON] Model
    )
```

Here is how `MultipartUpload` is defined.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
module Servant.Multipart
  ( MultipartUpload
  , FileInfo(..)
  ) where

import Data.ByteString.Lazy (ByteString)
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as Lazy
import Network.HTTP.Types (status400)
import Network.Wai.Parse
import Network.Wai (responseLBS)
import Servant
import Servant.Server.Internal


data MultipartUpload

instance (HasServer sublayout) => HasServer (MultipartUpload :> sublayout) where
  type ServerT (MultipartUpload :> sublayout) m =
    FileInfo ByteString -> ServerT sublayout m

  route Proxy subserver req respond = do
    dat <- parseRequestBody lbsBackEnd req
    let files = snd dat
    case files of
      [(_, f)] ->
        if Lazy.null $ fileContent f
          then respond . succeedWith $ responseLBS status400 [] "Empty file"
          else route (Proxy :: Proxy sublayout) (subserver f) req respond
      [] ->
        respond . succeedWith $ responseLBS status400 [] "File upload required"

      _ ->
        respond . succeedWith $ responseLBS status400 [] "At most one file allowed"
```

Comment: Note that this is VERY similar to the following combinator. I looked carefully at other combinators and I think I'm defining it correctly. What did I do wrong? https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/133#issuecomment-125235662

Answer (score 5):

Disclaimer: I've never used Servant, but I understand its approach.

Your `MultiPartUpload :> sublayout` handler is too eager. If you are always `respond`ing with `succeedWith`, then Servant has no way of knowing that it doesn't match and thus it should go on to trying the next alternative.

You'll need to use `failWith` in cases where you want to fall through to the next alternative.

You can see this is the case by checking out the `HasServer` instance for `:<|>`:

```
instance (HasServer a, HasServer b) => HasServer (a :<|> b) where
  -- ...     
  route Proxy (a :<|> b) request respond =
    route pa a request $ \mResponse ->
      if isMismatch mResponse
        then route pb b request $ \mResponse' -> respond (mResponse <> mResponse')
        else respond mResponse
```

this never looks at the second alternative unless the first response is a mismatch.

Comment: Thank you! So there's no way to appropriately pass on to the next route AND give an error to the user if they are missing a file on this route, correct?  And if I understand correctly, I could also fix this by giving my route with the upload a unique prefix? Like "models" / "uploads" / MultiPartUpload instead of "models" / MultipartUpload?

Answer (score 1):

I created a combinator that matches the http method earlier, so it can choose a route correctly and allow the MultipartUpload combinator to require an upload, instead of simply not matching.

I also filed an issue asking for clarification: https://github.com/haskell-servant/servant/issues/410

```
-- combinator that returns a mismatch if the method doesn't match
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
module Servant.Method where

import qualified Network.HTTP.Types as HTTP
import Network.Wai (requestMethod)
import Servant
import Servant.Server.Internal

data GET
data POST
data DELETE
data PUT

data Method a

class ToMethod method where
    toMethod :: Proxy method -> HTTP.Method

instance ToMethod GET where
    toMethod _ = HTTP.methodGet

instance ToMethod POST where
    toMethod _ = HTTP.methodPost

instance ToMethod DELETE where
    toMethod _ = HTTP.methodDelete

instance ToMethod PUT where
    toMethod _ = HTTP.methodPut

instance (ToMethod method, HasServer api) => HasServer (Method method :> api) where
  type ServerT (Method method :> api) m =
    ServerT api m

  route Proxy api req respond = do
    if requestMethod req == toMethod (Proxy :: Proxy method)
      then route (Proxy :: Proxy api) api req respond
      else respond . failWith $ WrongMethod
```

If I use it like this it solves the problem:

```
type ModelAPI =
  "models" :>
    (    ProjectKey :> Get '[JSON] [Model]
    :<|> ProjectKey :> Method POST :> MultipartUpload :> Post '[JSON] Model
    :<|> ProjectKey :> Capture "modelId" ID :> Get '[JSON] Model
    )
```